# Yup schema - Numbers less than 10 to have a trailing 0

Tags: typescript, yup

In Yup I have this schema:

```
const ticketVSchema = yup.object({
        team: yup
            .number()
            .required('The number is required')
    });
```

I need a condition to ensure if the user enters 0-9, it errors asking for a trailing 0, anything else is fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom [`.test()`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema) function that handles this logic.

```
const ticketVSchema = yup.object({
  team: yup
    .number()
    .test("is not 0-9", "asking for a trailing 0", value => {
      if (value && value > -1 && value < 10) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    })
    .required("The number is required")
});

ticketVSchema.isValidSync({team: 5}); // false
ticketVSchema.isValidSync({team: 10}); // true
```

Comment: I tried that but the problem is, even if `04` is entered, being a number, it's still viewed as `4`

Comment: `"04"` is not a number. Thus it will be invalid. If that is not what you want you'll have to allow `team` to be a `.string()`.